# {{^foreach}} not working in Ghost (0.9.0) Theme

Tags: handlebars.js, ghost

I'm working on a Ghost Theme and am having trouble getting the `foreach` helper to respect the `else` condition (or negation) in conjunction with `#get`.

#### Steps to Reproduce

1) Enable "Public API" in Ghost's "Settings > Labs > Enable Beta Features"
2) Add the following code to any .hbs page

```
{{!-- Obviously, this tag should not exist --}}
{{#get filter="tags:does-not-exist"}}

  {{#foreach posts}}
    foo
  {{else}}
    fails to show up
  {{/foreach}}

  {{^foreach posts}}
    fails to show up
  {{/foreach}}

  {{!-- Problem persists using #posts shorthand --}}
  {{#posts}}
    foo
  {{else}}
    fails to show up
  {{/posts}}

  {{^posts}}
    fails to show up
  {{/posts}}

{{/get}}
```

3) Check that page in your browser

**Expected Result**: "fails to show up" appears 4 times (once for each reference). 
**Observed Result**: "fails to show up" never appears

#### Notes

`#get` works as expected when the tag *does* exist. In the above code block, you'd see `foo` appear twice per post found.

`{{#foreach}}...{{else}}...{{/foreach}}` works as per [the documentation](https://themes.ghost.org/docs/foreach#section--else-and-negation) when used outside a `#get` helper. I had no difficulty reproducing their example:

```
{{#foreach tags}}
  <a href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
{{else}}
  <p>There were no tags...</p>
{{/foreach}}
```

#### Technical details:

- Ghost 0.9.0 and 0.8.0
- Node v4.4.7
- Chrome v52
- sqlite

See [Ghost Issue #7242](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/issues/7242)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I opened a [github issue](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/issues/7242), and received a solution there. You *should* be putting {{each}} directly on {{#get}}:

```
{{#get "posts" filter="tags:xyz"}}
  {{#foreach posts}}
    yeah posts
  {{/foreach}}
{{else}}
  no posts found
{{/get}}
```